# Pmset multiple repeating schedule pairs

Tags: bash, terminal, power, power-management

Can the pmset bash command be used with more than one repeating action pair?

For example:

Wake or Power on at 13:00, Sleep at 17:00

and

Wake at 18:00, Shutdown at 20:00

If not, is there an open-source tool that can accomplish this? Is there another tool that can turn on a computer at a certain time or is this only possible in pmset?

**EDIT:** I am looking for a tool that will work on all UNIX-like systems in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rtcwake` and `shutdown` to do that.

`rtcwake` is a utility to suspend the computer and wake it up after a certain period of time. The basic usage is

```
rtcwake -m <mode> -s <seconds>
```

For example

```
rtcwake -m mem -s 60
```

will suspend the computer to ram and wake it up after 60 seconds. It is possible to write scripts to invoke the desired actions in sequence, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# calculate seconds remaining until $1
seconds_until() {
    current_time=`date +%s`
    target_time=`date -d $1 +%s`
    seconds=`expr $target_time - $current_time`
    # wrap seconds
    [ $seconds -lt 0 ] && seconds=`perl -e "print $seconds+86400"`
    echo $seconds
}

# suspend and wake up at 13:00
rtcwake -m mem -s `seconds_until 13:00`

# wait until 17:00, suspend, and wake up at 18:00
sleep `seconds_until 17:00`
rtcwake -m mem -s `seconds_until 18:00`

# wait until 20:00 and shutdown
sleep `seconds_until 20:00`
shutdown -h now
```

Root privilege is required to use `rtcwake`.

Comment: Does this work in all unix-like systems? See edit.